# Ways to represent multivalued elements in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm trying to find the best way to make a table, eliminating the problems of redundancy and make it modular.

For example, suppose I have the following tables:

```
Company(id, name)
{
    1; IBM
    2; Google
    3; Amazon
}

Services(id, name)
{
    1; Phone
    2; Gas
    3; Electricity
    4; Water
    5; Heating
    6; Health service
    7; Education
    8; Transport service
}
```

I want to make a new table, the problem is that values are not mutually exclusive.

In the table, that I want make, I  must relate a company **(1)** with a certain numbers of services, the problem is that a company can have **(n)** number of services.

I thought of three different ways to do it, but I think these 3 modes violate the rules of database normalization.

Below I will write the 3 different modes, and some example records:

```
NewTableOne(company_id, servs)
{
    1; 3,5,7,8
    3; 1,2,5
}
```

The first record means the company IBM has services of Electricity, Heating, Education and Transport Service.
The second record means the company Amazon has services of Phone, Gas, Heating

```
NewTableTwo(company_id, service)
{
    1; 3
    1; 5
    1; 7
    1; 8
    2; 1
    2; 2
    2; 5
}
```

And the last,

```
NewTableThree(id, phone, gas, elect, water, heating, health, edu, transport)
{
    1; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1
    2; 1; 1; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0
}
```

It is convenient to employ any of these 3 ways?
Or is there a better way to do what I want to do, if so, how?

Thanks for reading and please excuse my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only version, that will **not** bring you into dire trouble is #2.

- You can't select all companies providing Electricity form #1 without a horrific performance penalty. SO is full of questions like "how do I select by a single value of a CSV field"
- You will run into max column limits with #3, even if you not yet think so. In addition to that, adding a service will need a change to the DB structure, which is not a good thing.

Comment: Is the redudancy in the second method "bad"? so, I should go with the second method or is there some other method that is different from those 3?

Comment: The  redundancy in #2 is minimal - in the order of magnitued of 25 bytes/row, so a million joins will need 25MB of space. If you use both columns as a primary index, you will also be really, really fast for lookups in the "natural" direction.

Comment: And, yes, this means go with #2.

Answer (score 1):

Your second provided solution is the best and easy to implement. It's called a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)